# Where is Anode Cap connected in CRT?

Tags: crt

On the expanding area of glass?
Is inside of expanding area metal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the anode cap is connected to a conductive layer on the *inside* of the glass envelope. It is a thin conductive graphite layer called **aquadag**. Electrons accelerated from the cathode exit the cathode ray tube here.
Both inside and outside of the glass envelope are conductive - it forms a capacitor which is the final filter that ensures that high-voltage is relatively constant, with small ripple.

The outside conductor on the glass envelope *must be grounded* for your protection.[image: three-cathode C.R.T. connections]

Comment: +1 There is often no conductive aquadag on the outside of small CRTs (oscilloscope, radar etc.). On larger tubes the built-in capacitor from ground to 2nd anode can provide an unwelcome surprise in the form of a jolt if it's charged and comes in contact with fingers etc.